# Change orientation of object while following path in game engine

Tags: game-engine

I am making a shooting gallery game. I have ducks following a circular path. When one of them is hit, i want it to flip on its back but still follow path. I could make two separate actions, one for hit, one for no hit and drive them by frame number in the game engine.

But i was wondering if i can simply apply a rotation to the duck while it is following the path when it is hit. If this is possible, can someone give me some guidance on doing so.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use two objects.

### Sledge

The base is the sledge that plays the path following animation.

### Duck

The Duck is parented to the sledge. When hit it plays the flip-back animation.

As it is parented to the sledge it will still follow the sledge movement.